# Easy way to create fallback installation of my system?

Tags: system-installation, package-management, backup

my current installation has lots of nice daemons installed/configured, Plugins for Firefox, nice packages installed.
I guess sooner or later I will trash my installation somehow.
I want to back up my system in a way, that after the reinstallation I have a fresh ubuntu with all the packages I need, and all the config files I set up for them (for example privoxy). Ideally I would like to have my fully configured Firefox in that new installation as well with my set of Plugins.
Is there an easy way to backup the list of installed packages with their config files?
Thank you so much!

**Edit**: I dont want to backup my whole filesystem, because over the years I probably acquired lots of junk laying around and slowing it down. What I want after the backup is a fresh system PLUS a list of packages with their config files

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I would call it "easy," but some sort of ghosting system (like Mondo Rescue) would be the best option here.